# What is the difference between the 'shell' channel and the 'exec' channel in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to be able to send many consecutive command represented as strings within a Java application to a SSH server for execution. Should I use:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
```

-or-

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With shell channel the shell (on Unix it's `sh` or `bash` or something like that, on Windows it's usually `cmd.exe`) is started and console is created (the same you see on the screen if you run them locally). You have a prompt which you can parse or use for detection of completion of command.

With command channel a shell instance is started for each command (actually the channel is opened for each command) and a command is passed as a parameter for the shell (on Windows it would look like "`cmd.exe /c <your command here>`".

It's easier to use command channel cause you don't need to deal with command prompt.

Comment: Actually, you can pass multiple commands to an exec channel - or a composite command, so to say. Simply separate them by `;` or `\n`.

Comment: @Paŭlo I would tend to call it "compound command". Also this is unix-specific notation -- in Windows it doesn't seem work (with cmd.exe, of course).

Comment: Right about the term - was to lazy to look it up. In general, this will depend on the shell (or interaction of the SSH server with the shell) - if cmd.exe does not accept multiple commands, bad for Windows users :-( (I have no Windows here to check this.)

Comment: It can be done for windows using `&` (i.e. The same effect of `;` on linux). Much more info can be found here (`&&`, `||`, `()`) https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=cmd+multiple+commands&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i have a problem with sourcing a script in the first ;=delimited token of a composite command, it sets and exports a var but the second part of the composite command does not see it.  e.g. ". ./.profile; echo $SOME_VAR_FROM_PROFILE" returns blank for the echo.  any idea?

Answer (score 20):

An overview about the differences and similarities between these streams you can find at »[Shell, Exec or Subsystem Channel](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Shell,_Exec_or_Subsystem_Channel)« in the JSch wiki. Here some details for your use case.

In the [**`exec` channel**](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html), the commands come from the command string you did give with `setCommand()`. The SSH server will pass them at once to the shell (using something like `bash -c '<command>'`).

They will all be executed, if the shell does not somehow exit before for some reason. (You could send a whole shell script here which implements some logic using `if` and similar, if this is wanted.)

So, to execute multiple commands, you could pass them to the exec channel by separating them with `;` or newline (`\n`). As you can't wait for the results before giving all the commands, here you can only use multiple exec channels (but as each channel spawns a new shell, they don't conserve state between them, like working directory or shell variables).

In the [**`shell` channel**](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell.html), the shell will read input from the stream, and interpret the first line as a command (or several ones).

Then it will execute this command. The command itself might read more input from the stream, if it wants.

Then the shell will read the next line, interpret it as a command, and execute.

(In some cases the shell has to read more than one line, for example for long strings or composed commands like if or loops.)

This will go on until either the end of the stream (e.g. stream.close() at your side) or executing an explicit exit command.

If you don't send any input to the shell via the channels input/output stream, the shell will simply wait until you either send more or close the stream. Thus you can quietly read the output of one command, do some calculations on the client side and then decide which command to send next.

Just make sure you don't mix input to one command with the text of the next command - preferably don't use any commands which will read from standard input.

Comment: what exactly is the Extended data of a channel?

Comment: In practice, this contains the content which the command/shell outputs to the "standard error" output stream. In theory, also other types of extended data would be thinkable, but [RFC 4254](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-5.2) defines only this type, and JSch does not allow distinguishing between different types.

Answer (score 9):

well, I found out that this works and it's really convenient if you want to preserve state like a regular shell would:

```
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        
OutputStream inputstream_for_the_channel = channel.getOutputStream();
PrintStream commander = new PrintStream(inputstream_for_the_channel, true);
        
channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
        
channel.connect();

commander.println("ls -la");    
commander.println("cd folder");
commander.println("ls -la");
commander.println("exit");
commander.close();
        
do {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} while(!channel.isEOF());
        
session.disconnect();
```

You could change

```
channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
```

to

```
InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channel.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.print(line+"\n");
```

if you want more control over the output.

=============================================================================

EDITED: follow up

why sometimes the commands I send through the PrintStream appear randomly in the output. i.e.
the following code:

```
shell[0].println("cd ..");
shell[0].println("cd ..");
shell[0].println("ls -la");
shell[0].println("exit");
```

produces this:
(marked with {thing} are things that shouldnt be there!)

> Last login: Thu Jul 21 21:49:13 2011 from gateway
>
> Manifests: trunk-latest
>
> [host ~]$ cd ..
> {cd ..}[host home]$
> [host home]$ cd ..
> [host /]$
> [host /]$ ls -la
> {exit}
>
> total 9999
> ----------  27 root root  4096 Jan 26  2010 .
> ----------  27 root root  4096 Jan 26  2010 ..
> ----------   1 root root     0 Mar 14 19:16 .autojyk
> ----------   1 root root     0 Feb  9  2009 .automan
> ----------   1 root root  3550 May 14  2010 .bash_history
> d---------   2 root root  4096 Apr 26 04:02 put
> d---------   5 root root  4024 Apr 25 19:31 boot
> [m[host /]$
> [host /]$ exit
> logout

Comment: You could try to switch off the terminal on the server side - maybe the shell then will not echo the commands. (Something like channel.setPty(false). Though I'm not sure what would be the default here.)

Comment: I tried this code and is working fine. But after connecting there are lot of messages getting displayed.. How to have control over the output such that only the commanders output alone gets displayed ??

Comment: @RageshKr, do you means get every command separately? Add split string to distinct command border, for example, `commander.println("echo 'COMMAND_BEGIN'");`  `commander.println("ls -la");`  `commander.println("echo 'COMMAND_END'");`

Answer (score 6):

It's not so much about JSch. It's about how the server implements the two channels.

---

In common *nix OpenSSH server:

- The `shell` channel executes a login shell (as if you login with SSH terminal client). The shell will then present a command prompt and wait for client/user to type the commands. The purpose of the `shell` channel is to implement an interactive shell session. That is something one will do very very rarely. If you do, you typically want to use terminal emulation.

  The `shell` channel is obviously used by SSH terminal clients (like OpenSSH `ssh` or PuTTY), under normal circumstances.

  The `shell` channel is a black box with an input and output. The input and output have no structure. If you for example execute a command by sending it to the input, you will never be able to tell when it ended. If you send two commands to input queue, you won't be able to distinguish what output comes from what command.
- The `exec` command takes a command as an "argument" and executes it in an isolated environment – still via user's default shell, but not as a "login" shell, what may cause significant differences in the command execution.

  The purpose of the `exec` channel is automating a command execution. So typically you do not want to use a terminal emulation, to avoid the command to do fancy stuff like pagination, coloring and mainly interactive confirmations.

  `exec` channel is used by OpenSSH `ssh` or PuTTY `plink`, when you specify a command to execute on its command line:

  ```
  ssh user@host command
  ```

---

With less common SSH servers, the difference can be even more significant. Some servers may even not support one of the channels. It is also quite common that they seemingly support both, but one of them (typically the `exec`) is completely broken.

---

There's a similar question for Python/Paramiko:
[What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)