# Not getting any output when using JSch to execute commands

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, jsch

I am trying to use JSch to execute `sudo su - user` command in a remote system first and then consecutively execute a piped shell command. I would like to read the command output into a `String`. How can I do this? I was trying something like this but could not get any output. Please advice.

```
session = getSession();
channel = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel( "shell" );
String sudoCommand = "sudo su - " + sudoAs;
String nextCommand = "ps -eaf | grep user | wc -l";
pipeIn = new PipedInputStream();
pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream( pipeIn );
channel.setInputStream(pipeIn);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
channel.connect(3*1000);
pipeOut.write(sudoCommand.getBytes());
Thread.sleep(1000);
pipeOut.write(nextCommand.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "Enter" (new-line) at the end of the commands.

So they actually never execute, that's why you cannot get any output.

```
String sudoCommand = "sudo su - " + sudoAs + "\n";
String nextCommand = "ps -eaf | grep user | wc -l\n";
```

---

Though in general, you should not use the "shell" channel to execute commands. Use the "exec" command.
See [What is the difference between the 'shell' channel and the 'exec' channel in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770206/850848#56713547)

Check the official JSch `Exec.java` example:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html